# How could I put a border on my grid control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I put a border on my grid in C#/WPF?

This is what I would like it to be, but puts a border around the whole thing instead of the grid control I put in my application.

```
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid Height="166" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" Background="#FFF2F2F2" />
    </Border>
... and so on ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "whole thing"?  I suspect you have something else inside your grid - you should perhaps post what that is.  My suspicion is that you have some kind of datagrid control as well as your grid container (which is what you've put in your sample and would presumably contain the "whole thing") and that's where the confusion arises.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

If you just want an outer border, the easiest way is to put it in a Border control:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
    <Grid>
       <!-- Grid contents here -->
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The reason you're seeing the border completely fill your control is that, by default, it's HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment are set to Stretch.  Try the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Border  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid Height="166" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" Background="#FFF2F2F2" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

This should get you what you're after (though you may want to put a margin on all 4 sides, not just 2...)

Comment: it does not work as i want... i've added some code to my question.

Comment: @Jason94: I updated my answer to show you how to get what I think you're after...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Reed, I know your solution works, what I don't understand is why the Border element is inside the Grid element - isn't this counter intuitive?  Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu You'll notice that my original didn't have that - I was making the OP's edit "work"

Comment: This seems to place a boarder around the inside of my main window and not around the outside of the grid that is encapsulated within it. Any ideas why?

Comment: Why not just put a border element inside the grid and leave it at that? 
Something like `<Grid><Border/><!--Rest of content--></Grid>`. Seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 10):

If nesting your grid in a border control

```
<Border>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

does not do what you want, then you are going to have to make your own control template for the grid (or border) that DOES do what you want.

Comment: oh... okey :D thought there were a variable i overlooked or something fancy WPF (im new at it :D)

Comment: You cannot create a Template for Grid and Border because they have no Template property as they are not derived from Control, but from Panel and Decorator. [Reed Copsey has the (pretty simple) solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769291/how-do-i-put-a-border-on-my-grid-in-wpf/2769312#2769312).

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that the margin should be specified in the border tag and not in the grid.

Answer (score 2):

This is a later answer that works for me, if it may be of use to anyone in the future. I wanted a simple border around all four sides of the grid and I achieved it like so...

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgDisplay" Margin="5" BorderBrush="#1266a7" BorderThickness="1"...
```

Comment: The `Grid` control does not have a `BorderBrush` attribute, but `DataGrid` does...

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid x:Name="outerGrid">
    <Grid x:Name="innerGrid">
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF179AC8" BorderThickness="2" />
        <other stuff></other stuff>
        <other stuff></other stuff>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This code Wrap a border inside the "innerGrid"

Comment: Hi @ElvinMammadov. Can you describe more. Are you getting any errors? This code works fine to me.

Comment: Need to add Grid.ColumnSpan="the columns you want to cover" Grid.RowSpan= "The rows you want to cover" in Border tag. Otherwise it only covers the first cell.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested in the similar problem, but is not working with XAML, here's my solution:

```
var B1 = new Border();
B1.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
B1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0); // You can specify here which borders do you want
YourPanel.Children.Add(B1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, wish useful for you:

```
public class Sheet : Grid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(BorderBrush), typeof(Brush), typeof(Sheet), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnBorderBrushChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(BorderThickness), typeof(double), typeof(Sheet), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1D, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnBorderThicknessChanged, CoerceBorderThickness));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CellSpacingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CellSpacing), typeof(double), typeof(Sheet), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0D, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnCellSpacingChanged, CoerceCellSpacing));

    public Brush BorderBrush
    {
        get => this.GetValue(BorderBrushProperty) as Brush;
        set => this.SetValue(BorderBrushProperty, value);
    }

    public double BorderThickness
    {
        get => (double)this.GetValue(BorderThicknessProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, value);
    }

    public double CellSpacing
    {
        get => (double)this.GetValue(CellSpacingProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(CellSpacingProperty, value);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Size size = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
        double border = this.BorderThickness;
        double doubleBorder = border * 2D;
        double spacing = this.CellSpacing;
        double halfSpacing = spacing * 0.5D;
        if (border > 0D || spacing > 0D)
        {
            foreach (UIElement child in this.InternalChildren)
            {
                this.GetChildBounds(child, out double left, out double top, out double width, out double height);

                left += halfSpacing + border;
                top += halfSpacing + border;
                height -= spacing + doubleBorder;
                width -= spacing + doubleBorder;

                if (width < 0D)
                {
                    width = 0D;
                }

                if (height < 0D)
                {
                    height = 0D;
                }

                left -= left % 0.5D;
                top -= top % 0.5D;
                width -= width % 0.5D;
                height -= height % 0.5D;

                child.Arrange(new Rect(left, top, width, height));
            }

            if (border > 0D && this.BorderBrush != null)
            {
                this.InvalidateVisual();
            }
        }

        return size;
    }
    
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);

        if (this.BorderThickness > 0D && this.BorderBrush != null)
        {
            if (this.CellSpacing == 0D)
            {
                this.DrawCollapsedBorder(dc);
            }
            else
            {
                this.DrawSeperatedBorder(dc);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DrawSeperatedBorder(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        double spacing = this.CellSpacing;
        double halfSpacing = spacing * 0.5D;


        #region draw border
        Pen pen = new Pen(this.BorderBrush, this.BorderThickness);
        UIElementCollection children = this.InternalChildren;
        foreach (UIElement child in children)
        {
            this.GetChildBounds(child, out double left, out double top, out double width, out double height);
            left += halfSpacing;
            top += halfSpacing;
            width -= spacing;
            height -= spacing;

            dc.DrawRectangle(null, pen, new Rect(left, top, width, height));
        }
        #endregion
    }

    private void DrawCollapsedBorder(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        RowDefinitionCollection rows = this.RowDefinitions;
        ColumnDefinitionCollection columns = this.ColumnDefinitions;
        int rowCount = rows.Count;
        int columnCount = columns.Count;
        const byte BORDER_LEFT = 0x08;
        const byte BORDER_TOP = 0x04;
        const byte BORDER_RIGHT = 0x02;
        const byte BORDER_BOTTOM = 0x01;
        byte[,] borderState = new byte[rowCount, columnCount];
        int column = columnCount - 1;
        int columnSpan;
        int row = rowCount - 1;
        int rowSpan;
        #region generate main border data
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            borderState[i, 0] = BORDER_LEFT;
            borderState[i, column] = BORDER_RIGHT;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            borderState[0, i] |= BORDER_TOP;
            borderState[row, i] |= BORDER_BOTTOM;
        }
        #endregion

        #region generate child border data
        UIElementCollection children = this.InternalChildren;
        foreach (UIElement child in children)
        {
            this.GetChildLayout(child, out row, out rowSpan, out column, out columnSpan);
            for (int i = 0; i < rowSpan; i++)
            {
                borderState[row + i, column] |= BORDER_LEFT;
                borderState[row + i, column + columnSpan - 1] |= BORDER_RIGHT;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < columnSpan; i++)
            {
                borderState[row, column + i] |= BORDER_TOP;
                borderState[row + rowSpan - 1, column + i] |= BORDER_BOTTOM;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region draw border
        Pen pen = new Pen(this.BorderBrush, this.BorderThickness);
        double left;
        double top;
        double width, height;


        for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
        {
            RowDefinition v = rows[r];
            top = v.Offset;
            height = v.ActualHeight;
            for (int c = 0; c < columnCount; c++)
            {
                byte state = borderState[r, c];

                ColumnDefinition h = columns[c];
                left = h.Offset;
                width = h.ActualWidth;
                if ((state & BORDER_LEFT) == BORDER_LEFT)
                {
                    dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(left, top), new Point(left, top + height));
                }
                if ((state & BORDER_TOP) == BORDER_TOP)
                {
                    dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(left, top), new Point(left + width, top));
                }
                if ((state & BORDER_RIGHT) == BORDER_RIGHT && (c + 1 >= columnCount || (borderState[r, c + 1] & BORDER_LEFT) == 0))
                {
                    dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(left + width, top), new Point(left + width, top + height));
                }
                if ((state & BORDER_BOTTOM) == BORDER_BOTTOM && (r + 1 >= rowCount || (borderState[r + 1, c] & BORDER_TOP) == 0))
                {
                    dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(left, top + height), new Point(left + width, top + height));
                }
            }

        }
        #endregion
    }

    private void GetChildBounds(UIElement child, out double left, out double top, out double width, out double height)
    {
        ColumnDefinitionCollection columns = this.ColumnDefinitions;
        RowDefinitionCollection rows = this.RowDefinitions;
        int rowCount = rows.Count;

        int row = (int)child.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        if (row >= rowCount)
        {
            row = rowCount - 1;
        }

        int rowSpan = (int)child.GetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty);
        if (row + rowSpan > rowCount)
        {
            rowSpan = rowCount - row;
        }
        int columnCount = columns.Count;

        int column = (int)child.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
        if (column >= columnCount)
        {
            column = columnCount - 1;
        }

        int columnSpan = (int)child.GetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty);
        if (column + columnSpan > columnCount)
        {
            columnSpan = columnCount - column;
        }

        left = columns[column].Offset;
        top = rows[row].Offset;
        ColumnDefinition right = columns[column + columnSpan - 1];
        width = right.Offset + right.ActualWidth - left;
        RowDefinition bottom = rows[row + rowSpan - 1];
        height = bottom.Offset + bottom.ActualHeight - top;
        if (width < 0D)
        {
            width = 0D;
        }

        if (height < 0D)
        {
            height = 0D;
        }

    }
    private void GetChildLayout(UIElement child, out int row, out int rowSpan, out int column, out int columnSpan)
    {
        int rowCount = this.RowDefinitions.Count;

        row = (int)child.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        if (row >= rowCount)
        {
            row = rowCount - 1;
        }

        rowSpan = (int)child.GetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty);
        if (row + rowSpan > rowCount)
        {
            rowSpan = rowCount - row;
        }
        int columnCount = this.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        column = (int)child.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
        if (column >= columnCount)
        {
            column = columnCount - 1;
        }

        columnSpan = (int)child.GetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty);
        if (column + columnSpan > columnCount)
        {
            columnSpan = columnCount - column;
        }
    }

    private static void OnBorderBrushChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (d is UIElement element)
        {
            element.InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }

    private static void OnBorderThicknessChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (d is UIElement element)
        {
            element.InvalidateArrange();
        }
    }

    private static void OnCellSpacingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (d is UIElement element)
        {
            element.InvalidateArrange();
        }
    }

    private static object CoerceBorderThickness(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        if (baseValue is double value)
        {
            return value < 0D || double.IsNaN(value) || double.IsInfinity(value) ? 0D : value;
        }

        return 0D;
    }
    private static object CoerceCellSpacing(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        if (baseValue is double value)
        {
            return value < 0D || double.IsNaN(value) || double.IsInfinity(value) ? 0D : value;
        }

        return 0D;
    }
}
```

a demo:
[image: demo of a table with collapsed border]

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Is there any possibility to add something like CellPadding?

Comment: you can modify ArrangeOverride

Answer (score 1):

If attempting to wrap a Grid that has been seperated into Columns and Rows, you can use the span option like so.

```
<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  Grid.Row ="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" ShowGridLines="True" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
</Grid>
```

Gives you this:
[image]